# Symfony/Twig: internal ID for form widgets?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've to modify the `radio_widget` and would like to give the `<label>` and `<input>` the same **ID**, which should be **unique** for each pair.

Currently I'm using [random()](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/random.html), but I'd prefer an internal counter, something like `{{loop.index}}` ([Twig: for](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html)), to avoid conflicts.

```
{% block radio_widget -%}
    {% set id = random() %}
    <div class="radio">
        <label for="radio_{{ id }}">Label for {{ id }}</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio_{{ id }}" {# ...#}/>
    </div>
{%- endblock radio_widget %}
```

Does anyone know a better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're talking about the main radio widget used for form-rendering? If so, you already have a widget-dependent unqiue id in: `form.vars.id`.

Comment: @Yoshi exactly what I've needed. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every form-widget there already exists a pre-calculated unique id.

See: `\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BaseType::buildView`

In twig this ID is accessible through `{{ form.vars.id }}`.

In essence the id is just a concatenation of the nested form-type names.

---

Note that `form.vars` in general contains all the useful *stuff* you'd need to do form-customization. It's also the place to put custom values when using `FormTypeInterface::buildView` or `FormTypeInterface::finishView` to transport data to the form rendering.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ProjectTwigExtension.php</kbd>

```
class ProjectTwigExtension extends Twig_Extension {

    public function getFunctions() {
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFunction('get_unique_key', array($this, 'getUniqueKey')),            
        );
    }

    private $keys = array();
    /**
    *   Create an unique HTML identifier for a form element
    *
    *   @param $name String to make unique
    *
    *   @returns String
    */
    public function getUniqueKey($name) {
        if (!in_array($name, $this->keys)) {
            $this->keys[] = $name;
            return $name;
        }
        $i = 0;
        while(in_array($name.++$i,$this->keys)) {}
        $this->keys[] = $name.$i;
        return $name.$i;
    }


    public function getName() {
        return 'ProjectTwigExtension';
    }        
}
```

<kbd>config.php</kbd>

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addExtension(new ProjectTwigExtension());
```

<kbd>template.twig</kbd>

```
{% block radio_widget -%}
    {% set id = get_unique_key('radio_') %}
    <div class="radio">
        <label for="{{ id }}">Label for {{ id }}</label>
        <input type="radio" id="{{ id }}" {# ...#}/>
    </div>
{%- endblock radio_widget %}
```

Comment: Good solution in general, but this time I only need `form.vars.id`. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try something like this:

```
{% block radio_widget -%}
  {% if counter is defined %} {# set desired id #}
    {% set id = counter %}
  {% else %}
    {% set id = random() %} {# default value #}
  {% endif %}
    <div class="radio">
        <label for="radio_{{ id }}">Label for {{ id }}</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio_{{ id }}" {# ...#}/>
    </div>
{%- endblock radio_widget %}
```

Example of use:

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
  {% set counter = loop.index %}
  {{- block('radio_widget') }}
{% endfor %}
```